# Partition key paths must contain only valid characters and not contain a trailing slash or wildcard character

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

I use Azure CLI to created a container in database but it's always through for me an error like this:

```
[\"The partition key component definition path 'C:\\/Program Files\\/Git\\/zip1' could not be accepted, failed near position '0'. Partition key paths must contain
```

only valid characters and not contain a trailing slash or wildcard character."]}

My azure cli is like this:

```
az cosmosdb sql container create --account-name testaccjul1 --resource-group demo-app-test --database-name cosdbjul2 --name container1 --partition-key-path '/zip' --throughput 400
```

Could anyone tell me where I am wrong? thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, in case it helps anyone: I used double forward slash when using git bash and it worked for me.

`--partition-key-path "//zip"`

Answer (score 0):

Please put the partition key path in double quotes. Something like:

```
az cosmosdb sql container create --account-name testaccjul1 --resource-group demo-app-test --database-name cosdbjul2 --name container1 --partition-key-path "/zip" --throughput 400
```

This is based off of example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/sql/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-sql-container-create-examples).

Comment: I already update like that but it's not working for me

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the updated code.

Comment: I just created a container using the command I provided in my answer without any errors.

Comment: I dont know why but I use that command line still through for me an error the same

Comment: Where are you running this command from? I ran it directly from the terminal.

Comment: I run it by gitbash